# How to print array as specific format?

Tags: python, arrays, format

I have an array formatted like this:

```
[-22.99253267 -83.23210952  77.71126322  43.99377722 -41.75731176 89.02862477]
```

I would like to print this array to receive this result

```
[-22.992 -83.232  77.711  43.993 -41.757 89.028]
```

I know It will be a similar result if I use `np.set_printoptions(precision=3)`, but I would like to know how to receive this result using `9.3f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print the data in column :

```
for data in x:
    print '{:9.3f}'.format(data)
```

or

To print the data in row :
(don't forget `import sys`)

```
for data in x:
    sys.stdout.write('{:9.3f}'.format(data))
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I have one more question. How can i print it as a row, not as column??

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer but the answer was already here.

Comment: Quick question myself NPE if you don't mind. Is there any benefit to printing the data into a row rather than appending it onto a list?

Comment: @BGlasbey suppose your array is thousands of floats data long, you will have to store this list of strings in memory before printing. So it is memory consuming and time consuming. Just print the data and be done with it.

Comment: @J.Park It wasn't a question of comparing row format to column format. Every body likes it how it wants. I believe what @BGlasbey wanted me to have the opportunity to say is that doing `for numbers in list: x = '{:9.3f}'.format(data) y.append(x) print(y)` is a waste of memory and time.

Answer (score 0):

Using [String.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
list = [-22.99253267, -83.23210952,  77.71126322,  43.99377722, -41.75731176, 89.02862477]
for numbers in list :
    print('{:9.3f}'.format(data))
```

I receive the output

```
-22.993
-83.232
 77.711
 43.994
-41.757
 89.029
```

**EDIT**

Following OP's comment, here's an update which would append all elements into a list.

```
y = []
list = [-22.99253267, -83.23210952,  77.71126322,  43.99377722, -41.75731176, 89.02862477]
for numbers in list:
   x = '{:9.3f}'.format(data)
   y.append(x)
print(y)
```

Output

```
['  -22.993', '  -83.232', '   77.711', '   43.994', '  -41.757', '   89.029']
```

Comment: Perhaps by `data`, you meant `numbers` in `.format`. Second, you have successfully converted `list` into a list of strings!